# Is this true-- Riemann sum and partition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

If $R(f,P,T) <0$ for every partition pair P,T on the interval $[a,b]$, then $\int_{a}^b f(x) dx<0.$

I think this is false since the Riemann sum may exist for $f(x)$; however, it does necessarily mean that the integral exists.

Similarly, If $R(f,P,T) =0$ for every partition pair P,T on the interval $[a,b]$, then $\int_{a}^b f(x) dx=0.$

I think this is false for similar reasons.

Or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: I take it $T$ is a set of tags for the partition $P$?

Comment: For your second problem, note for any $x\in[a,b]$, by considering $P=\{[a,b]\}$ and $T=\{x\}$, one deduces $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Yes. I should have clarified that.

Comment: @DavidMitra: would you be willing to walk to me through an intuitive explanation of the problem? I am finding hard to build intuition in these problems.

Comment: My issue is I can have a $f(x)=x$ from $-1$ to $1$, then the area under the curve is zero, but $f(x)$ is not; how did you deduce that $f(x)=0$?

Comment: For that function, there are Riemann sums that do not have value $0$. In your second problem, you have a very strong condition: *every* Riemann Sum is $0$. In fact then, $\lim\limits_{\Vert P\Vert\rightarrow0} R(f,P,T)=\lim\limits_{\Vert P\Vert\rightarrow0} 0=0$; thus $f$ is integrable over $[a,b]$ with  $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=0$ (my previous comment shows even more: given $x$, by selecting  a particular Riemann sum, you can show $f(x)=0$).

Comment: Should f(x)=0 always? I am just confused about that part. When you say a particular R. Sum, you mean a particular partition, right?

Also, what about the first statement, am I right in thinking that?

Comment: Yes to your first question. Take the partition to just be $\{[a,b]\}$ and take the tag to be the fixed $x$. Then the associated Riemann sum is $f(x)(b-a)$. This is zero by assumption, so $f(x)=0$ (assuming $a\ne b$). The reasoning for the first part is fine. Riemann sums always exist, but the integral may not. To be complete, you might want to give an example of a function that isn't integrable but such that $f(x)<0$ for all $x$ (take $f(x)=-2$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=-17$ if $x$ is irrational, e.g.).